# How to fix 'invalid list of files to parse' error when compiling SASS files?

Tags: css, sass

Input Error: You must pass a valid list of files to parse

$ npm run prefix:css

> natours@1.0.0 prefix:css
> postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 5 versions'

Input Error: You must pass a valid list of files to parse

compiling sass file
however getting an error on the prefix compilation anyone with a quick help please could really use some cause I am quite stuck